# .desktop launcher providing arguments results in "No such file or directory"

Tags: freedesktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=launcher
Comment=
Exec=sh -c "echo hi"
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
```

results in

```
Failed to launch child: sh -c 'echo hi'
With error: No such file or directory
Press Enter to exit.
```

According to my research, this should work. What is going on here? How can I diagnose this issue?

Comment: I suspect you will need to write a script instead, but just in case, does `Exec='sh -c "echo hi"'` (putting the entire command in single quotes) work?